# How to use Provider to show or hide FAB?

Tags: flutter, provider

I'm just starting to look at alternatives to `setState()` and therefore Provider. In the first program that I am looking at to implement Provider, the only `setState()` that I use is on the initial `build()`, and also when data changes in order to display a FAB when the FAB is not already displayed. There are six `TextField` widgets in this program, and they all have `TextEditingControllers`, so they all have their own state.

Is it feasible to use Provider in this situation when `_tfDataHasChanged (bool)` changes, and if so, how?

Code is below for the FAB creation:

```
Widget _createFab() {
    if (_tfDisplayOnly || !_tfDataHasChanged) return null;
    return FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: _btnSubmitPressed,
      backgroundColor: _colorFab,
      mini: false,
      tooltip: _sBtnSubmitText /* Add or Create */,
      child: _iconFab,
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can:

```
Widget _createFab( BuildContext context) {

    boolean showFab = Provider.of<ShowFab>(context).shouldShow;
    return showFab?FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: _btnSubmitPressed,
      backgroundColor: _colorFab,
      mini: false,
      tooltip: _sBtnSubmitText /* Add or Create */,
      child: _iconFab,
    ):null;   
}
```

with the ShowFab class looking like

```
class ShowFab with ChangeNotifier {
  boolean shouldShow;

  void showFab( boolean show ){
    shouldShow = show;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Obviously your specific logic will be different, 
The ShowFab needs to be provided higher in the widget tree.

```
ChangeNotifierProvider<ShowFab>( builder: (context) => ShowFab(), child: .... )
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.